# How to set custom ListAdapter to list view in appwidget?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, remoteview

I have a listView. I needed a custom view for each list item, so I've created a custom ListAdapter which gives the views, layout for which is given below. But how do I set this listAdapter to the ListView in the widget using RemoteViews ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:layout_margin="1sp"
    android:padding="10sp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widgetInfo1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/listItemDummy"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widgetInfo2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/listItemDummy"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want a listadapter for this listview or do you want it for a remoteview ? also what have you tried ?

Comment: I want to add ListView to a widget, which has the custom view items. That is my basic requirement, so I created a listAdapter but it seems that you can not use the normal listAdapter and add to ListView in widget.. Above layout is for the single view item in list...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the common `Adapter`, for `RemoteViews` you need to implement [`RemoteViewsFactory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory.html). To return custom `RemoteView`'s (yes, `RemoteView` for each item and not `View`), you will need to override its [`getViewAt(int position)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory.html#getViewAt%28int%29) method.

Also, one just does not `setAdapter()` for `RemoteView`s, you would need to provide a [`RemoteViewsService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViewsService.html) which will return above `RemoteViewsFactory` to its clients.

Finally, to the client that is going to show the `RemoteView`s, you pass an `Intent` of this service.

The Service and its Intent you will need to declare in your manifest file. This will make your App a provider of remote List like views to other apps or any remote process.

Comment: Are you suggesting something like:

remoteViewsServiceIntent 
     = new Intent(
       context
       , MyRemoteViewsService.class);

Comment: @AmolKamble http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#collections

Comment: How to pass custom data (my list of items from API) to this adaptor?